# How to estimate the parameters of a hypergeomtric distribution?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, hypergeometric-distribution

I am looking for some guidance on how to estimate the parameters of a hyper-geometric distribution, based on a random sample.

For example, if I generate a distribution as follows:

```
set.seed(101)
hyper_dist <- rhyper(250, m = 50, n = 20, k = 30)
```

I'd like to be able to figure out how to estimate the values of m, n and k from the given sample.

In the past I used MLE techniques to estimate parameters for other distribution types, however I am finding it difficult to find literature that provides formulas so i can code my own R functions.

If anyone can provide a breadcrumb trail as to how I estimate these parameters it would be much appreciated.

I did find a paper here -> https://documat.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/7390757.pdf but I am unclear how to determine the distribution parameter values, as neither m, n, or k are known.

Thanks
Jonathan

Comment: Please describe your actual sample rather than some hypothetical computer calculation.  The question is strange, because ordinarily one of these parameters (`k`) is the sample size--something one usually doesn't need to estimate!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "check the probability"?  This doesn't require any kind of estimate: it reads like a direct probability calculation.

Comment: Ok how about the classic deck of cards example, If i have 52 cards in a deck, and I draw 8 cards from the deck, if a measure of success is drawing 4 red cards from the deck, I would have parameters N=52, n=8 K=26 and k=4

Comment: I have to repeat my previous comment: there doesn't seem to be any kind of estimation involved in that situation.  A better way to make progress would be to edit your post to explain the situation you actually face, rather than trying to ask about some kind of hypothetical problem.

Comment: I deleted and restated my comment as it looks like I was confusing rather than clarifying. To restate the original question, I was looking to understand if it is possible to estimate the parameters of a hyper-geometric distribution, if this is not reasonable please let me know.

Comment: Again: it depends on how you collected your data.  A classic example is a capture-recapture experiment.  Another example is sampling without replacement from a small finite population.  *These require different techniques.*  We can't answer your question until we know what it's really about!